# How to implement scheduler with Windows Form Application in VB.Net

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am working on Windows application which is developed in VB.NET. This application contains multiple analytical tests. When user clicks on particular test then encrypted SQL queries gets executed and corresponding output got pasted in Excel.

Now the requirement is auto-scheduling this task where user will specify date and time and at that particular time test should get executed. Also SQL queries are stored in encrypted format for security purpose so I cannot use SSIS package or SQL job agents for scheduling the tasks.

What possible approaches/workaround can be used with this particular scenario for implementing scheduler for .NET Windows Application?

Comment: Could you create a simple console application that does your treatment and then run it through Window's own scheduler?

Comment: I agree with Gimly, where ever batch processes or daily tasks need to be performed its best to have these tests or reports as different executable as console applications. then simply create a task on windows task scheduler

Comment: We are using [Quartz Scheduler](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) where Windows scheduled tasks won't do.

Comment: A few months ago I had the same task, to execute queries on a scheduled basis and put the result in an Excel doc. I solved it by creating my own service in C#. We store queries and the desired schedule in database, my service get this data and execute the statements on the correct times.

Comment: @Kevin what approach you have used for scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll try to explain the approach we used. We have a web ui, a database and 2 windows services, 
one that is used to update the schedule information and one that is responsible for exporting to Excel.

**Database**

A table to store our queries together with his schedule information.
A table to store all exports, so we can keep history.

**Web UI**

Through a webinterface we can store queries that need to be executed automatically on a scheduled basis, 
some hourly, some daily, some weekly and some monthly. 
On the interface the user can makes his disered configuration for the schedule.

When the query is saved, we immediately calculate the nextruntime of this query through a self written 
SQL function and store this value in the database. Each time an update happens for a record, ex query changes or the
schedule info changes, we update the field lastmodified.

**Services**

Our first service reads in all information where the field nextruntime is not null. This information we keep in memory in an object list.
Every 5 minutes we check if there is a change made to that export, because the query can be changed or the schedule information 
is updated. If a we find an updated record we update this information in the object list.
In the same service we loop every 30 seconds over the object list and see if the nextruntime equals the actual system datetime. If so
we add a record to the second table with a certain status, so the second service knows which records needs to be processed and we also keep an incremental
sequence number so it exports them in order.

Our second service polls the second table and is responsible for executing the query, exporting the result to Excel, and when it's done update the 
nextruntime field in the first table based on the schedule information. For creating the Excel files we used the OpenXml library.

I hope it's a bit clear to you.